# Unable to replace variable in json body in postman

Tags: javascript, json, postman

I have a situation where a for loop should run in pre-request script and should save the value. The same set of values should be used in the body ie it should be used as a unique identifier. Can someone suggest me on how to do this?

In pre-script,i have saved the value like mentioned below:

```
var id = [];
for(var i = 20; i <= 25; i++) {   
         pm.environment.set('id', i);
}
```

In the json body, i need to have email values like "testemail1@tester.com", testemail2@tester.com" where the numbers should be populated based on the values from  pre-request script. Could you please help me here???

Comment: Doesn't `testemail{{id}}@tester.com` do that? What have you tried?

Comment: Also you're continually overwriting what `id` is so you will ever set with that code 25

Comment: As @DannyDainton said:
You set a variable in the pre-request script via pm.environment.set('myVariable', 'value').
In the body, you then need to put {{myVariable}}. During execution, that will be replace by 'value'.

Comment: I added a new env variable and it worked fine :)